# Solutions to the diophantine equation $x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3=1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What is known about the solutions $(x,y,z,w)\in \mathbb{Z}^4$
of the diophantine equation
$$x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3=1$$
Can you suggest me a book or a paper treating this problem?

Comment: in rational or whole numbers?

Comment: The solutions in integers.

Comment: I think there are a few options. The easiest is. Use this formula. https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1046691__2  Substituting in it the solution of the equation Pell for example. $7p^2-9ps+3s^2=1$

Comment: @individ:  I have proved that all rational is a sum of four cubes of rational (PRO MATHEMATICA. VOLUMEN XIII / Nos. 25-26). There is an old conjecture that all integer is a sum of four cubes of integers (similar to the famous Lagrange's theorem for squares) and has been proved that it is true for all integer not of the form $9n\pm 4$. It remains open problem the conjecture for this class of integers.

Comment: @individ: Seeing your link in Russian, I find it very interesting. Fortunately, the equation $57p ^ 2-15ps + s ^ 2 = 1$ (condition sine qua non to apply these formulas to the problem proposed here) has integer solutions and therefore solutions to the problem can be found. This way, for example give the solution $(-6, -1, -5,\space7)$.

Comment: @Piquito Every rational number is a sum of _three_ rational cubes; this has been known for quite a while.

Comment: @Ivan Neretin.- Yes, but how deduce of this that also it goes for four non-zero cubes?

Comment: @Piquito: why, that's simple. One of four is an _arbitrary_ rational number, and the rest are adjusted so as to produce the necessary sum, which is always possible.

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**.-The equation $x^3+y^3+z^3+w^3=n$ has an infinity of integer solutions if there exists one solution $(a,b,c,d)$ such that $$-(a+b)(c+d)\gt 0$$ is not a perfect square, and $a\ne b$, or $c\ne d$.

(*See Diophantine equations, L. J. Mordell. Academic Press, p. 58*).

Since $\mathbb F_7^3=\{0,\pm1\}$ necessarily one of the unknowns is a multiple of $7$ because if not we would have 
$$(\pm1)+(\pm1)+(\pm1)+(\pm1)\equiv 1\pmod7$$ which is impossible.

Trying to find a particular solution I find out $(x,y,z,w)=(14,\space 30,-23,-26)$ which satisfies the conditions of the above theorem. Thus, there are infinitely many solutions which are related, according to the mentioned book, to a Pell's equation (*which as it is well known has an infinity of integer solutions*).

Answer (score 1):

In general it is clear that for such an equations there are infinitely many solutions. For example
$$(n,-n,1,0),\; n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
and permutations. Another, less obvious, possibility is to consider the infinite family of solutions 
$$(9n^4,3n-9n^4,1-9n^3,0)\; n\in \mathbb{Z}$$
It could be interesting to know if all the solutions are contained in a finite number of curves or surfaces.
For a similar problem:
$$x^3+y^3+z^3=1$$
there is a nice discussion in the paper of D.H. Lehmer "On the diophantine equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=1$". I'm searching for an analogous paper in which is considered the case of four variables.

Comment: I had given the same parameterization as you but I deleted my answer because it is nothing other than $x^3+y^3+z^3=1$. That is why I edited giving now the one that appears in my current answer. You can see the Mordell's book I have mentioned to know about what you want.

Comment: In the Mordell's book is described only the case of 3 variables and the reference is the paper of Lehmer.

Comment: See edition year 1969 ACADEMIC PRESS INC. (LONDON) LTD. Page 58 where besides you can see the proof of the theorem below (Library of Congress Catalog Card Number: 68-9112). Regards.

Answer (score -1):

This can be solved in pieces:

1. $a+b+c+d=1$
2. $(x)\mapsto x^3$ (used 4 times)
3. $\mathbf{Z}^4$ integer lattice

To solve the problem, we need inverse image. The 1st step is just a bar of length 1 split to 4 parts from arbitrary places(in $\mathbf{R}$). in 2nd step, inverse of $x^3$ is just cube root $\sqrt[3]{x}$. 3rd step those cube root values need to hit the lattice points in the integer lattice. So to get solution, we need to understand how cube root behaves. There's a path $$1 \mapsto (a+b+c+d) \mapsto (a,b,c,d) \mapsto (\sqrt[3]{a},\sqrt[3]{b},\sqrt[3]{c},\sqrt[3]{d}) \mapsto P$$ $$ (k_1Z_1+k_2Z_2+k_3Z_3+k_4Z_4) \mapsto P$$, where the first two $\mapsto$ generates infinite tuples satisfying (1), and the last $\mapsto$ filters them away, with $a,b,c,d \in R$ and $k_1,k_2,k_3,k_4 \in Z$. There's a pullback $R^4 \times_P Z^4$.

Note, if you want solutions out from this construct, you should remove the "diophantine" keyword, and thus the lattice disappears, and you can then get solutions from the path. Approximate solution will implement the pullback as just $(x,y,z,t)
 \mapsto (\lfloor{x}\rfloor,\lfloor{y}\rfloor,\lfloor{z}\rfloor,\lfloor{t}\rfloor)$, where there's $\pm 1$ error in the results for each element.

Comment: Note: calculating cuberoot can be done via "factorisation method", i.e. factor the numbers and find out where factors come in groups of 3. I.e. if  $3 \times 3 \times 3$ is your number, then obviously $3$ is a factor of the cuberoot.